# Unity DI - C# Dependency Injection how to use with a repository class constructor ? It's only intended for controllers?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container

i wanna know if it's possible to inject dependency for a class constructor as it is injected for controllers, i have the following cenario as an example:

An AccountController which depends on an AccountRepository like bellow:

```
public AccountController(IAccountRepository repository)
```

The dependency is injected perfectly using Unity DI, which have the following configuration:

```
container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(), accountInjectionConstructor);
        container.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, ApplicationDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

The problem is that i have a class AuthorizationServiceProvider which also needs the AccountRepository... In this case, how would i instantiate or use this AuthorizationServiceProvider class without having to instantiate and provide it all the dependencies?

```
Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider>(),
```

This provider is set inside the Startup class and called before the Unity DI config initializes...

Here the visual studio complains that there's no argument given that corresponds to the class constructor, but if i provide a new AccountRepository i'd have to provide all it's dependencies as well, (ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager userManager) which are already provided for the Unity DI when creating the controllers....

[image]

Could somebody help me please?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You should try to learn more about the idea and principles of Dependency Injection. There's much more to learn than anyone can answer in one SO question. A good place to start is [this paper](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/4/7aa4ddd-002a-4b2a-8ba1-4570a3215131/Seemann2_DEidotNET2E_MEAP_V11_ch1.pdf).

Comment: Hi Steve! I'll check it out... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

> how would i instantiate or use this AuthorizationServiceProvider class without having to instantiate and provide it all the dependencies?

You can't. This is actually the core of what we're trying to achieve with Dependency Injection. Your *application code* should *let go* of the control over its dependencies. This means that your application code should *not* create an `AuthorizationServiceProvider`. Rather, it should let a **third-party** provide this dependency. Typically, this means you require the dependency be supplied using **Constructor Injection**.

Letting application code create these dependencies itself causes problems, typically referred to as the **Control Freak** anti-pattern or **Dependency Inversion Principle** violation. It causes *strong coupling*, which can hinder maintainability.

When working with Dependency Injection, this third-party is called the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/). The Composition Root is:

> a (preferably) unique location in an application where modules are composed together.

With DI, only the Composition Root will create graphs of objects. You are using Unity, which is a DI Container. The DI Container acts as the **Composer**, which is part of your Composition Root.

Instead of using a DI Container, you can build the object graphs by hand, which means you will have to create a complete tree of dependencies at once. This practice is called **Pure DI**. Still, the Composition Root is *the* location where those object graphs are created; with or without a DI Container.

Your view of DI might be troubled by the use of the standard Identity template that Visual Studio provides. From a design and DI perspective, however, this template is horrifying.

Either way, all these stated concepts, patterns and anti-patterns are described quite thoroughly in the book [Dependency Injection in .NET by Mark Seemann](https://mng.bz/BYNl).